# Is it possible to change Kendo ComboBox option items' width on event?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I've got a limited display width for a Kendo ComboBox, so in it's normal state, I need to to be fairly narrow.  The option items take advantage of a "template" and are much wider that the ComboBox. I'd like to update the width when the ComboBox is clicked/engaged by the user, and while the js/css changes I've been making seem to work, the option items do not display in the correct width until the 2nd time the combobox is clicked - the the actual combox box width changes.

```
@Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
             .Name("Type")
             .BindTo(Model.Types)
             .Events(e => { e.Open("TypeOpen"); })
             .Template("<div style='width: 300px'>${ data.Text }</div>")
```

// js

```
function TypeOpen() {
  $("#Type").closest(".k-widget").css("width", "300px");
}
```

// after first click; it looks good after the 2nd click

[image: after first click]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put your DropDownList in a div you can control the drop down list size using a css:

```
    <div id="myCombo">
        @Html.Kendo().ComboBox().HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50px" }) 
                     .Name("Type")
                     .BindTo(Model.Types)
                     .Events(e => { e.Open("TypeOpen"); })
                     .Template("<div style='width: 300px'>${ data.Text }</div>")
    </div>

   <style>
     #myCombo-list
        {
            width: 100px !important;
        }    
   </style>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I was able to get this to work without using the div as well. I just added the styling to #Type-list. Is there a problem I'm not seeing by doing that? I couldn't get it to work by inserting this css during the event - is there any way that would be possible?

Comment: Don't see a problem with including the list style the way you described...Not sure why it would not apply during event binding.